# Initializing queue of structures using replication in System verilog

Tags: system-verilog

How can we initialize a queue of structure with replication when non-replicated elements are also present? I tried out below ways without success. Is it even possible?

```
typedef struct {
 A a;
 B b;
 C c;
 D d;
} lp_s;    //A,B,C,D : integer enums

lp_s var_name[$] = '{    
     '{a: A_VAL0, b: B_VAL1, default:0}
'{15{'{a: A_VAL1, b: B_VAL1, default:0}}},
     '{a: A_VAL2, b: B_VAL2, default:0}
};
```

Error here is :

> Assignment pattern is illegal due to: Replication field exceeds the
>   size of the target

I removed the tick from replication.

```
lp_s var_name[$] = '{    
         '{a: A_VAL0, b: B_VAL1, default:0}
     {15{'{a: A_VAL1, b: B_VAL1, default:0}}},
         '{a: A_VAL2, b: B_VAL2, default:0}
    };
```

Then error became:

> Unpacked Structure of type 'lp_s' can't be assigned by multiple
>   concatenation operator {15 {'{a: A_VAL1, b: B_VAL1, default:0}}}
>   However assignment pattern can be assigned to unpacked structures. Add
>   a '    before concatenation operator to convert it to a valid
>   assignment pattern.

Or is there a way to achieve using unpacked array concatenation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an explicit type to an assignment pattern so it can be used in a self-determined context.

```
typedef lp_s lp_sq[$];

lp_s vari[$] = { // unpacked array concatenation of struct assignment patterns
                lp_s'{a: A_ENUM, b: B_ENUM, C: J_ENUM, D: D_ENUM},
               lp_sq'{12{lp_s'{a: A_ENUM, b: B_ENUM, C: J_ENUM, D: D_ENUM}}},
                lp_s'{a: A_ENUM, b: B_ENUM, C: J_ENUM, D: D_ENUM }
};
```

Note, you can't use `default:0` here because `0` is not a valid value type to assign to an `enum`.